# Docker, using OS container + php container separately

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I have a basic understanding on what is a container and how it differs from a virtual machine. But one aspect of Docker workflow I can't figure out is how to run OS container + any other container. Use case:

I need to run *CentOS 7.2* + *Apache* + *php5.6* + *MySQL*

My question is more like: how to connect these containers to serve *Apache* + *php5.6* + *MySQL* from CentOS container.

I can just use CentOS container and setup all software inside it but that looks strange and would defeat the purpose of Docker I think.

All tutorials I have found is about PHP, Apache, MySql containers but they run on HOST kernel.

Comment: what is a "CentOS container"? Is it just a container with an image based on CentOS?

Comment: Well it's https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/ for example.

Comment: But why do you need such a bare container? what application runs inside it? In general, Apache + php5.6 + MySQL is sufficient for a web application.

Comment: This is web app specific things, I need CentOS 7.2 no way around. And also some times I would like to replicate production environment 100%. Also all dev's should have same enviroment, with same kernel and libraries.

Comment: I don't think we are on the same page here. Let's suppose that you have a container that is based on the CentOS oficial image. What do you put inside that container, what kind of software? Because one application would run inside the container that is based on PHP5.6. What other application have you that runs at the same time with the PHP application that runs in the PHP5.6 container?

Comment: @RomkaLTU it seems you haven't grasp what are containers about yet. Constantin is right.

Comment: Maybe we're not, I think I'm missing important puzzle here. Anyway. I don't know what libraries or binaries I need to have, but I know that CentOS out of the box install have it in specific places (which defined in web app). Probably all linux distro's have it but path is different. So for example my app doesn't run on Ubuntu or Debian this is rare case but thing is that I need to run LAMP in specific CentOS version.

Comment: You should run your webserver container inside a centos based image then for instance.

Comment: So it means I can't some how use existing containers? Just 1 OS container?

Comment: You don't need any OS container, you are supposed to work on your regular machine (Windows, Ubuntu, you name it). Maybe you confuse Docker with virtualization and you want to have IDE tools and such installed? In that case Docker won't help you.

Comment: Yes but if I need different kernel or OS then my HOST have? I know that containers is just a process which use HOST kernel (if they run on Linux).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169562/discussion-between-emix-and-romkaltu).

Comment: So in my case it's better to use Vagrant?